# DQN reinforcement learning for function optimization

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to write a pytorch DQN Reinforcement Learning python script to optimize a simple function of two variables. I am failing in making it converge.

Can you tell me what is wrong in my code ?

```py
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.optim as optim
    import numpy as np
    from collections import deque
    # Define an environment
    class Environment():
        def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
            self.state_size = state_size
            self.action_size = action_size
            self.state = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, self.state_size)
            self.next_state = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, self.state_size)
            self.reward = 0.
            self.it = 0
            self.k = 0
            self.done = False



        def reset(self):
            self.state = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, self.state_size)
            self.next_state = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, self.state_size)
            self.reward = 0.
            self.it = 0
            self.k = 0
            self.done = False
        # Define the quadratic function to optimize
        def func_to_optimize(self,x):
            def phi(t):
                k = 0.
                if t < 0:
                    return 0
                else:
                    return k*t**3
            p = 1.
            return -((x[0] - 0.5) ** 2 + (x[1] - 0.5) ** 2) - phi(2*x[0] + x[1] - 1)
        def step(self, action):
            eta, zeta = 1E-2, 1E-3
            if action == 0:
                self.next_state[0] = self.state.copy()[0] - eta
            if action == 1:
               self.next_state[0] = self.state.copy()[0] + eta
            if action == 2:
               self.next_state[1] = self.state.copy()[1] - eta
            if action == 3:
               self.next_state[1] = self.state.copy()[1] + eta
            delta = self.func_to_optimize(self.next_state) - self.func_to_optimize(self.state)
            if abs(delta) < zeta:
                self.k += 1
            self.done = (self.k > 1)
            alpha = 0
            self.reward = delta + alpha
            if self.done:
                self.reward = 1000*self.func_to_optimize(self.state)
            return (self.next_state, self.reward, self.done, None)
       
    # Define the deep Q-network (DQN) used by the agent
    class DQNNetwork(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
            super(DQNNetwork, self).__init__()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 16)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(16, 16)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(16, output_dim)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
            x = self.fc3(x)
            return x

    # Define the DQN agent
    class DQNAgent():
        def __init__(self, net, target_net, action_size, memory_size,
                 epsilon=1, gamma=1., lr=0.0001):
            self.net = net
            self.target_net = target_net
            self.action_size = action_size
            self.epsilon = epsilon
            self.gamma = gamma
            self.optimizer = optim.AdamW(self.net.parameters(), lr=lr)
            self.memory_size = memory_size
            self.memory = deque(maxlen=memory_size)

        def act(self, state):
            # Epsilon-greedy policy
            if np.random.uniform() < self.epsilon:
                return np.random.choice(np.arange(self.action_size))
            else:
                state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)
                with torch.no_grad():
                    q_values = self.net(state).squeeze(0).numpy()
                return np.argmax(q_values)

        def train(self, batch_size):
            if len(self.memory) < batch_size:
                return
            batch = np.random.choice(len(self.memory), size=batch_size, replace=False)
            states = torch.tensor([self.memory[i][0] for i in batch], dtype=torch.float32)
            actions = torch.tensor([self.memory[i][1] for i in batch], dtype=torch.float32)
            rewards = torch.tensor([self.memory[i][2] for i in batch], dtype=torch.float32)
            next_states = torch.tensor([self.memory[i][3] for i in batch], dtype=torch.float32)
            done = torch.tensor([self.memory[i][4] for i in batch], dtype=torch.bool)
            q_values_next = self.target_net(next_states).max(1)[0]
            q_targets = rewards + (1 - done.float()) * self.gamma * q_values_next
            #q_targets = rewards + self.gamma * q_values_next
            q_values = self.net(states).gather(1, actions.long().unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
            #loss = nn.functional.smooth_l1_loss(q_values, q_targets.detach())
            loss = nn.functional.smooth_l1_loss(q_values, q_targets.detach())
            #loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(q_values, q_targets.detach())
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()

        def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
            self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    # Define the main function for optimizing the function
    def optimize_function():
        state_size = 2  # Dimensionality of the state space
        action_size = 4  # Dimensionality of the action space
        memory_size = 10000  # Maximum size of the replay memory
        batch_size = 1024  # Batch size for training the DQN network
        num_episodes = 10000  # Number of episodes to run the training
        max_it = 10000 # Number of iterations for optimization
        eps_start, eps_end, eps_decay = 1, 0.01, 0.99 # Parameters for epsilon variation
        update_every = 10 # Frequency of model update
        env = Environment(state_size, action_size)
        # Initialize the DQN network and agent
        net = DQNNetwork(state_size, action_size)
        target_net = DQNNetwork(state_size, action_size)
        agent = DQNAgent(net, target_net, action_size, memory_size, epsilon=1, gamma=.999, lr=0.0001)
   
        scores = []
        # Run the learning episodes
        agent.epsilon = eps_start
        for episode in range(num_episodes):
            # Run the environment iterations to find the optimum
            # Reinitialize environment
            env.reset()

            score = 0
            for i in range(max_it):  
                env.it += 1
                # Choose an action and perform it
                env.action = agent.act(env.state)
                # Update environment from choosen action
                env.next_state, env.reward, env.done, _ = env.step(env.action)
                # Remember the transition and train the agent
                agent.remember(env.state, env.action, env.reward, env.next_state, env.done)
                if i%update_every == 0:
                   agent.train(batch_size)
                # Update the state
                env.state = env.next_state.copy()
                score += env.reward
                scores.append(score)
                if env.done:
                    break
            #agent.train(batch_size)
            agent.epsilon = max(eps_end, eps_decay * agent.epsilon)
            TAU=0.05
            for key in net.state_dict():
                target_net.state_dict()[key] = net.state_dict()[key]*(TAU) + target_net.state_dict()[key]*(1-TAU)
            target_net.load_state_dict(target_net.state_dict())

            # Print the episode score
            if episode % 10 == 0:
                print(f"Episode {episode + 1}: Score = {score}")
                print(f"State {env.state}", f"Number of iterations {i}", f"epsilon {agent.epsilon}",)
        return agent, scores, env
    agent, scores, env = optimize_function()*your text*`
```

This code does not converge to the solution (0.5, 0.5).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).